# Revolution slider image zoom out

Tags: jquery, drupal, slider, loading, revolution-slider

in my Drupal site, the slider image zooms out than the original, I'm unable to fix this . Please help. For your reference I'm attaching the screenshot here.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRB65.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not zooming out, you are using small picture that is stretched because the slider is much bigger.

Go to slider settings and see what is the actual size of the slider.
Then open the photoshop and create a new project with this dimensions, for example 1200px x 600px and find a picture that you can place inside that will look good - don't stretch it, find a nice big picture.

Then upload this picture as your slider background image and everything will be perfect.

Comment: thanks for your reply, as you said the slider settings are set to slider:width&height: 960px x 460px, and my image size is 1920px x 420px. Why is my image zooming out

Comment: make your image 960x460, your aspect ratio is off thats why is "zooming out"

Comment: or you can change size of your slider if its too small, but in any way size of your slider should be the same size as picture or if the picture is bigger it should have the same aspect ratio as the size of the slider

Comment: Thanks a lot, u made my day :)

Comment: @goran You seem to be an expert on SLider Revolution. Can you take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42730487/slider-revolution-in-wordpress-previous-slider-image-zooms-in-before-next-image